# maintaining a Box's appearance as screen size changes in MaterialUI ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm having a small yet annoying issue with an Avatar I have in my MaterialUI sidebar.

I'm attempting to make the following Avatar (wrapped with a Box mui component) to remain proportional as screen size changes:
[image]

So far what's happening is that the image slowly slowly disappears as the screen shrinks.

The Navbar component is being called from the following **Farmers.js** file:

```
import { Paper } from '@mui/material'
import React from 'react'
import NavbarFolds from '../Components/Navbar/NavbarFolds'
import useFarmersState from '../Hooks/useFarmersState'
import FarmersComponent from '../Components/FarmersComponent'

const Farmers = () => {
    let [farmerslistVal, farmerslistValEdit] = useFarmersState();

    console.log(farmerslistVal);
  return (
    
    <Paper> 
    {/* <Headerbar/> */}
    <NavbarFolds />
    {/* <FarmersComponent farmerslistVal={farmerslistVal}/> */}
    
    </Paper>
  )
}

export default Farmers
```

and this is my **NavbarFolds.js**:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { styled, useTheme } from '@mui/material/styles';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import MuiDrawer from '@mui/material/Drawer';
import MuiAppBar from '@mui/material/AppBar';
import Toolbar from '@mui/material/Toolbar';
import List from '@mui/material/List';
import CssBaseline from '@mui/material/CssBaseline';
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';
import Divider from '@mui/material/Divider';
import IconButton from '@mui/material/IconButton';
import MenuIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Menu';
import ChevronLeftIcon from '@mui/icons-material/ChevronLeft';
import ChevronRightIcon from '@mui/icons-material/ChevronRight';
import ListItem from '@mui/material/ListItem';
import ListItemButton from '@mui/material/ListItemButton';
import ListItemIcon from '@mui/material/ListItemIcon';
import ListItemText from '@mui/material/ListItemText';
import InboxIcon from '@mui/icons-material/MoveToInbox';
import MailIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Mail';
import { useState } from 'react';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import { navbarItems } from './Const/navbarItems';
import logo_img from '../../Images/logo.png';
import { Avatar, Menu, MenuItem, Tooltip } from '@mui/material';

const drawerWidth = 240;
const settings = ['Profile', 'Account', 'Dashboard', `${true ? "Log out" : "Log in"}`];


  const NavbarFolds = () => {
  const [anchorElNav, setAnchorElNav] = React.useState(null);
  const [anchorElUser, setAnchorElUser] = React.useState(null);

  const handleOpenNavMenu = (event) => {
    setAnchorElNav(event.currentTarget);
  };
  const handleOpenUserMenu = (event) => {
    setAnchorElUser(event.currentTarget);
  };

  const handleCloseNavMenu = () => {
    setAnchorElNav(null);
  };

  const handleCloseUserMenu = () => {
    setAnchorElUser(null);
  };

const openedMixin = (theme) => ({
  width: drawerWidth,
  transition: theme.transitions.create('width', {
    easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
    duration: theme.transitions.duration.enteringScreen,
  }),
  overflowX: 'hidden',
});

const closedMixin = (theme) => ({
  transition: theme.transitions.create('width', {
    easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
    duration: theme.transitions.duration.leavingScreen,
  }),
  overflowX: 'hidden',
  width: `calc(${theme.spacing(7)} + 1px)`,
  [theme.breakpoints.up('sm')]: {
    width: `calc(${theme.spacing(8)} + 1px)`,
  },
});

const DrawerHeader = styled('div')(({ theme }) => ({
  display: 'flex',
  alignItems: 'center',
  justifyContent: 'flex-end',
  padding: theme.spacing(0, 1),
  // necessary for content to be below app bar
  ...theme.mixins.toolbar,
}));

const AppBar = styled(MuiAppBar, {
  shouldForwardProp: (prop) => prop !== 'open',
})(({ theme, open }) => ({
  zIndex: theme.zIndex.drawer + 1,
  transition: theme.transitions.create(['width', 'margin'], {
    easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
    duration: theme.transitions.duration.leavingScreen,
  }),
  ...(open && {
    marginLeft: drawerWidth,
    width: `calc(100% - ${drawerWidth}px)`,
    transition: theme.transitions.create(['width', 'margin'], {
      easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
      duration: theme.transitions.duration.enteringScreen,
    }),
  }),
}));

const Drawer = styled(MuiDrawer, { shouldForwardProp: (prop) => prop !== 'open' })(
  ({ theme, open }) => ({
    width: drawerWidth,
    flexShrink: 0,
    whiteSpace: 'nowrap',
    boxSizing: 'border-box',
    ...(open && {
      ...openedMixin(theme),
      '& .MuiDrawer-paper': openedMixin(theme),
    }),
    ...(!open && {
      ...closedMixin(theme),
      '& .MuiDrawer-paper': closedMixin(theme),
    }),
  }),
);

  let navigate = useNavigate();
  const theme = useTheme();
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);

  const handleDrawerOpen = () => {
    setOpen(true);
  };

  const handleDrawerClose = () => {
    setOpen(false);
  };

  return (
    <Box sx={{ display: 'flex', marginTop: "2%" }}>
    <Menu
              sx={{ mt: '45px' }}
              id="menu-appbar"
              anchorEl={anchorElUser}
              anchorOrigin={{
                vertical: 'top',
                horizontal: 'right',
              }}
              keepMounted
              transformOrigin={{
                vertical: 'top',
                horizontal: 'right',
              }}
              open={Boolean(anchorElUser)}
              onClose={handleCloseUserMenu}
        >
              {settings.map((setting) => (
                <MenuItem key={setting} onClick={handleCloseUserMenu}>
                  <Typography textAlign="center">{setting}</Typography>
                </MenuItem>
              ))}
            </Menu>
      <CssBaseline />
      <AppBar position="fixed" open={open}>
        <Toolbar>
          <IconButton
            color="inherit"
            aria-label="open drawer"
            onClick={handleDrawerOpen}
            edge="start"
            sx={{
              marginRight: 5,
              ...(open && { display: 'none' }),
            }}
          >
            <MenuIcon />
          </IconButton>
          
          <img src={logo_img} style={{width:"35px", marginRight: "5px"}} sx={{ position: "fixed", display: {xl: 'flex', l: 'none'}, mr:1}}/>
          
          <Box>
          <Typography variant="h6" noWrap component="div" style={{letterSpacing: "3px"}}>
            iFarm
          </Typography>
          </Box>


          <Box sx={{ flexGrow: 1, position: "relative", marginLeft: "87%", display: {xl: 'flex', l: 'none'}}}>
          <Tooltip title="Open settings">
               <IconButton onClick={handleOpenUserMenu} sx={{ }}>
                 <Avatar alt="Remy Sharp" src="/static/images/avatar/2.jpg"  />
               </IconButton>
             </Tooltip>
          </Box>


        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
      <Drawer variant="permanent" open={open}>
        <DrawerHeader>
          <IconButton onClick={handleDrawerClose}>
            {theme.direction === 'rtl' ? <ChevronRightIcon /> : <ChevronLeftIcon />}
          </IconButton>
        </DrawerHeader>
        <Divider />
        <List>
          {navbarItems.map((item, index) => (
            <ListItem key={item.label} disablePadding sx={{ display: 'block' }}>
              <ListItemButton onClick={ () => navigate(item.route)}
                sx={{
                  minHeight: 48,
                  justifyContent: open ? 'initial' : 'center',
                  px: 2.5,
                }}
              >
                <ListItemIcon
                  sx={{
                    minWidth: 0,
                    mr: open ? 3 : 'auto',
                    justifyContent: 'center',
                  }}
                >
                  {index % 2 === 0 ? <InboxIcon /> : <MailIcon />}
                </ListItemIcon>
                <ListItemText primary={item.label} sx={{ opacity: open ? 1 : 0 }} onClick={ () => navigate(item.route)} />
              </ListItemButton>
            </ListItem>
          ))}
        </List>
        <Divider />
      </Drawer>
      {/* <Box component="main" sx={{ flexGrow: 1, p: 3 }}>
        <DrawerHeader />
      </Box> */}
    </Box>
  );
    
}
export default NavbarFolds;
```

Now, I notice that the Box wrapping the Avatar is wrapped by a Toolbar, AppBar and a Box, in order. I'm a bit confused regarding who of the parents should I refer to, and how.

Bonus question :p
what is the impact of the 3 dots in the underlined line, and the line.
[image]

Thanks for any attempt to help!

Answer (score 1):

The `<Avatar />` disappears because of the `marginLeft: "87%"`.
`position: relative` is not doing anything.
Also you have wrong brakepoint, its `lg` not `l`.

```
<Box
  sx={{
    display: { lg: "none", xl: "flex" },
    flexGrow: 1,
    justifyContent: 'flex-end'
  }}
>
  <Tooltip title="Open settings">
    <IconButton onClick={handleOpenUserMenu}>
      <Avatar alt="Remy Sharp" src="/static/images/avatar/2.jpg" />
    </IconButton>
  </Tooltip>
</Box>
```

The dots that you are asking about is called [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) in js and this is one way of passing conditional styles to the `sx` prop. It **merges** the new styles and if the style property is already there is going to **overwrite** it.
More about the `sx` styling solution: https://mui.com/system/getting-started/the-sx-prop/